# React Live-Search with Fetch API

Tags: reactjs, fetch, livesearch

I wonder how to deal with live-search feature implementation in React using Fetch API.

**Problem:** Responses of calls to API via Fetch can come back in a wrong order.

I was thinking about adding timestamp to the requests, but I think there has to be some better solutions for such common feature.

This is the code I have so far:

```
const TagPicker = ({ className }) => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    const [proposedTags, setProposedTags] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = e => {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setSearchText(val);

        async function fetchTags() {
            const res = await fetch(`api-url/${val}`);
            res.json()
                .then(res => setProposedTags(res))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }

        val.length ? fetchTags() : setProposedTags([]);
    };

    return(
        <div className={className}>
            <Input placeholder="Name a tag" value={searchText} onChange={handleChange} />
            <TagList tags={proposedTags} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TagPicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my example with debounce [example with hooks](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ReactWarriors/reactwarriors-select-with-async/tree/demo?file=/src/App.hooks.js)

Comment: If I understand that correctly then this is making it slower but doesn't deal with the order in which the responses come in. Or does it somehow solve the problem and I just can't see it? Thank you :)

Comment: This allows you to not immediately send a request for each user input, but only after 500 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Well if they are coming back in the wrong order, then it should be the server's responsibility to present the response in the right order.

You can do something like

```js
const res = await fetch(`api-url/${val}/asc`); //to get it in ascending order for example
```

Depending on the server you have of course, you can also sort it on the frontend (not recommended)m which will be exactly as you mentioned, using a timestamp or some other value.

Comment: I didn't mean the order of the data coming from the server. What I meant is that you send multiple requests in very short time and they come back not in the order I sent them out in.